# IOS : Readjusting a UITableViewCell according the height of a UIImage in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, image, tableview

So I have been trying to adjust the size of my tableView Cells according to the size of an image that I get from an API call that I make.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/iKjzK.jpg

The images that I get are in a 5:4 ratio.
What i've done in the screenshot is put a fixed height under

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    let viewWidth = self.view.frame.size.width
    let imageHeight = (viewWidth * 5) / 4
    return imageHeight
}
```

(I've ignored small things like cell Paddings and stuff)

Even though the image doesn't look too bad, i'm not happy with what i've done. I have also tried

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
    if image != nil {
        return image.size.height
    } else {
        return DEFAULT_HEIGHT
    }
}
```

Which gives me a cell size where the image's height is being stretched. What is the correct way to do what i'm trying to achieve?

EDIT: I wanted to find a way so that the image automatically adjusts itself.

For example, 
Right now, the images that I receive from the backend are in the ratio 4:5.
Hypothetical situation if they change it to a 1:1 ratio, I would want it to adjust itself. Any suggestion?
Also, my storyboard is going bonkers when i add the aspect ratio.
TIA!

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you use Autolayout for your cell, put the ImageView inside the cell and give it trailing and leading constraints of 0(or your margin) and an aspect ratio constraint of 5:4?

Comment: Hi Rajeev, so i had tried out what you said without removing my heightForRowAtIndexPath, it looked fine. Now its height is too less.
So right now i have a "roundedCornerView" which is a custom class which is at 3 constraints to top left and right (gives its a nice padding) and 0 to the bottom. The imageView is at 0 constraints on sides of this rounded corners view at 4:5 AR.
Heres what I got
http://i.imgur.com/KdPpjQg.png
TIA. 
Also if it helps my storyboard is giving me a warning that says "Height and Vertical Position are ambiguous for 'Rounded Corners View' "